# wants to show the data b/w the same date or two different dates

Tags: c#, database, c#-4.0

I want to show the data b/w same or different dates. Here is my code, when i run this it is showing the data_grid view as empty.

```
  SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Sales where InvoiceDate BETWEEN  '" + S_reportFromDate.Text + "' AND '" + S_ReportToDate.Text + "'", con);
  DataTable t = new DataTable();
  sda.Fill(t);
  ByDateReport_Grid.DataSource = t;
```

Comment: may be you don't have any data between those dates. check your database.

Comment: SQL Injection alert!  Please use parameterized queries.

Comment: there is a data between dates which i am entering